# What's the best approach to drawing a colored picture

Tags: drawing, tool-selection, colored-pencils

I'm not an avid artist, but when I draw, I usually just sketch in pencil because it's such a simple and forgiving drawing tool. I thought I'd try drawing a colored picture, but I'm a bit lost at how to do it. My first instinct is to use colored pencils because it is a somewhat forgiving tool, but it is harder to erase than plain pencil. I also don't know if I should do a basic sketch in pencil, then erase it and go over it in colored pencil. What is the best technique? Are there special art colored pencils that would be significantly better than regular crayolas?

Comment: Hi Ryan! I think this has potential, but you need to focus your question - "best" is subjective, but something like "What are the main techniques for colored pencils" could work (but possibly too broad, unless you have a particular thing to draw in mind). Asking for particular brands of colored pencils is off-topic as we don't do shopping recommendations, but you could ask about the difference between student and artist quality pencils, or what types of colored pencils are available (as a separate question).

Answer (score 0):

**I also don't know if I should do a basic sketch in pencil, then erase
 it and go over it in colored pencil**

You absolutely can do this - try using a harder pencil like a 7H or 5H and keep your lines light so you won't have to cover up as much later.

**What is the best technique?**

The question is too broad to answer well, but I think your first instinct to try colored pencils is a good one - they are forgiving and familiar.

**Are there special art colored pencils that would be significantly better than regular crayolas?**

Yes, there is a big difference between Crayola and the higher end colored pencils by Prismacolor, Derwent, etc. At many art supply and craft stores you can buy individual colored pencils if you'd like to see the difference without dropping a lot of money on a full set.